# Python TikTakToe game if statement not working properly

Tags: python

So I am writing a python tiktaktoe game as a project. I am required to use multidimensional arrays and have no errors. In the function p_turn() (Which manages the player move), I was going to implement an if statement to check whether the move is valid (between 1 and 3). But now, no matter what number I put in, it still says that the move is invalid.

The desired outcome is for the game not to allow numbers that aren't between 1 and 3.

```
def p_turn():
    system(command='cls')
    print_board()
    p_play_1 = int(input("Choose a position for the Y between 1 and 3 -->  "))
    p_play_2 = int(input("Choose a position for the X between 1 and 3 -->  "))
    if p_play_1 != 1 or p_play_1 != 2 or p_play_1 != 3 or p_play_2 != 1 or p_play_2 != 2 or p_play_2 != 3: # This is whats not working correctly
        print("This is not a valid move. The values must be betweeen 1 and 3! ")
        time.sleep(3)
        p_turn()
    if board[p_play_1 - 1][p_play_2 -1] == " ":
        board[p_play_1 - 1][p_play_2 - 1] = "X"
        system(command='cls')
        print_board()
        c_turn() # Computer play
    elif board[p_play_1 - 1][p_play_2 - 1] == "X" or [p_play_1 - 1][p_play_2 - 1] == "O":
        print("Someone already went there! ")
        time.sleep(3)
        p_turn()
```

Also, if it's important, this is how I store my board.

```
board = [[" ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " "],
         [" ", " ", " "]]

def print_board():
    print()
    print(f"{board[0][0]} | {board[0][1]} | {board[0][2]}")
    print("---------")
    print(f"{board[1][0]} | {board[1][1]} | {board[1][2]}")
    print("---------")
    print(f"{board[2][0]} | {board[2][1]} | {board[2][2]}")
    print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `p_turn` to `player_turn`. That way you give your function much more meaning. The same applies to `c_turn` - `cumputer_turn` is far more clear. In your small example, it doesn't make that big a difference but in larger projects, naming is really important!

`p_play_1` and `p_play_2` would make much more sense if they were simply named `x` and `y`.

Your boundary check is essentially:

```
if x != 1 or x != 2 or x != 3 or # ... repeat for y
```

That can't work. The above `if` condition is evaluated from left to right and terminates as soon as something is `True`. Take for example `x = 2` (which is a valid coordinate). `x != 1` evaluates to `True` and your move is considered invalid.

There are many ways to check whether a variable is within a certain *range* in Python.

Using  comparison operators:

```
if lower_bound <= value <= upper_bound:
    # value is between lower and upper bound
```

Using `range()`:

```
if value in range(lower_bound, upper_bound + 1):
    # value is between lower and upper bound
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
while not 1 <= (p_play_1 := int(input("Choose a position for the Y between 1 and 3 -->  "))) <= 3:
    print(f"Invalid Y position: {p_play_1}")

while not 1 <= (p_play_2 := int(input("Choose a position for the X between 1 and 3 -->  "))) <= 3:
    print(f"Invalid X position: {p_play_2}")
```

Comment: Just to note, the `:=` syntax requires Python 3.8 or greater.